# Can some unsolvable problems in mathematics be associated with an uncomputable number?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, computability

I'm a bit sheepish asking this since I know close to nil on uncomputability.
I ask mainly due to Chaitin's constant, which to my knowledge, is the probability that any given program will halt or not, though I'm not sure if the logic behind the undecidability of the halting problem is similar to that of, for example, the continuum hypothesis (independence from ZFC implying unanswerability).

If an un(dis)provable statement could be written in the form:

$\text {There always exists some A such that B is satisfied}$

Is the probability that any given A satisfies B uncomputable

---

Small note: initially my thoughts were to let P be the probability that for any set S chosen from the set of all sets with cardinality less $\aleph_2$,

$\aleph_0 <|S|<\aleph_1$,

which is how I arrived at the above idea

---

edit: I'll narrow it down further to let A be a real in the interval $[0,1]$ and 'any given A' be a real from $[0,1]$

Comment: What is meant by "the probability that a statement is true"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'll adapt my question to be more specific, I admit it was a bit bold to go too vague.

Comment: What is meant by "the probability that any given A satisfies B"? To talk about probabilities, you need to specify some way of picking A at random, e.g. by specifying some probability measure on some probability space containing A.

Comment: I'll narrow it down further to let A be a real and 'any given A' be a real from $\mathbb R$

Comment: And how do you pick a real number at random? There is a canonical probability measure on the unit interval $[0,1]$, but not on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can't you biject [0,1] onto R?

Comment: Sure, but there are many ways to do this. Different bijections will give you different probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. I didn't say there is no way of picking a real number at random, just that there is no *canonical* way. So if you want to talk about probabilities, you need to specify your measure.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  I recognise you can't have a uniform probability distribution over the naturals, but that is really interesting. I suppose for simplicity, I'll narrow down my question over the interval [0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chaitin's Omega story is a rather special one, and not something associated with non-computability in general. It was already discussed in the comments that only few mathematical structures come with a natural probability measure on them, but even for $[0,1]$ we don't get lucky. As $[0,1]$ is connected, its only decidable subsets are $\emptyset$ and $[0,1]$ itself, so sets of measure other than $0$ and $1$ are always undecidable.

Fixing that issue, we can consider $2^\omega$ with the fair coin toss measure instead. But we can still easily built undecidable sets of any desired measure, as messing around with a measure 0 set suffices for undecidability.

Comment: So it doesn't matter whether or not the statement is independent from ZFC?

Comment: Oh wait, but if the statement is not independent from ZFC, it's either 0 or 1 for any given value (depending on whether the statement has or has not been disproven)?

Comment: On an informal note, does unprovability always imply independence from ZFC and vice versa, because I looked at Turing's proof and it seemed to involve some degree of set notation, but I've never seen it in reference to the axioms despite seeming close to fundamental as something like the continuum hypothesis